# How to add values in a map with a vector as a value type?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, vector

Overview: I have some code which iterates through a list of strings (name) to find the last character of each string. I also have a myGraph typedef map which takes in a struct as value type. The struct contains vector nodenext and vector next_cnt.

To do: I need to initialize vector nextwt_vec to be an empty vector each time a new char is inserted in the map.

Problem: With the below code, my nextwt_vec retains the old value of the previous char.

```
    map<char, vector<int> > nextmap;


 for (myGraph::const_iterator j = graph.begin(); j != graph.end(); ++j)
 {
    vector<int> nextwt_vec;
    //populating next map with char and weighted ints
    for (int p=0; p< (int) (*j).second->nodenext.size(); ++p)
    {

        char cn = name[name.length() - 1];

        int wt = (*j).second->next_cnt[p];

        nextwt_vec.insert(nextwt_vec.begin()+p, wt);

        //puts char as key and weighted int as value in nextmap
        n->nextmap[cn] = nextwt_vec;

    }
```

Output: What I get:

```
char: A   vec: 109 
char: C   vec: 109 vec: 48
```

Output that I should get:

```
char: A   vec: 109
char: C   vec: 48
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Move the declaration `vector<int> nextwt_vec;` *inside* the `for` loop.

Comment: I don't get it. Where do you output text? What does `char: C   vec: 109 vec: 48` mean?

Comment: @KerrekSB when I do that, I get a segmentation fault: 11 error

Answer (score 0):

Drop vector nextwt_vec; variable from the function. Work directly with nextmap[cn].
Replace these two lines:

```
    nextwt_vec.insert(nextwt_vec.begin()+p, wt);

    //puts char as key and weighted int as value in nextmap
    n->nextmap[cn] = nextwt_vec;
```

with this:

```
    //puts char as key and weighted int as value in nextmap
    n->nextmap[cn].insert(nextwt_vec.begin()+p, wt);;
```